# Views grid - align fields

Tags: views

I'm using Drupal 7, and I have a content type called Book, which consists of a picture and a title. I'm using Views (grid format) to display Books on a page, and it's working great. The only problem is that the titles always sit directly under the picture, which looks bad if the pictures are of different heights. Is there a way to horizontally align all fields within a grid?

This is what I currently have:

```
_____   _____   _____
|    |  |    |  |    |
|    |  |    |  |    |
|____|  |    |  |____|
title   |____|  title
        title
```

And this is what I want:

```
_____   _____   _____
|    |  |    |  |    |
|    |  |    |  |    |
|____|  |    |  |____|
        |____|  
title   title   title
```

I've managed to achieve this by overriding views-view-grid.tpl.php (and adding a new row to the table for each field), but was wondering if there was a better way?

Update: I'm not interested in solutions that involve changing the layout / picture sizes. This is the second time a designer has given me a PSD that leaves me facing this issue, so I'd really like to find a good solution to this exact problem!

Answer (score 1):

If the images are of different sizes, it might look a lil sloppy. You can use CSS to set a particular height and width for all the images so that they look uniform and I guess overriding views-view-grid.tpl.php just for this is not the best way.

Comment: Thanks for your response, but I don't want to change the size of the images. I'm leaving the design to the designers - and this is how they want it.

Answer (score 0):

This is the way I used to do it.  http://www.advomatic.com/blogs/amanda-luker/table-free-gallery-grid-view-drupal-theming  However this post is a bit dated.  That said, same size images really is the way to go if you can, or set a definite height.

Comment: That blog post solves the slightly different problem of the alignment between rows of items. My problem is with the alignment of fields within a single row of items.